# How enable GZIP compression for Spring HttpInvoker requests using Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, gzip

Wondering if anyone has set up GZIP compression for Spring HttpInvoker requests using Tomcat, and what steps are necessary?

Also, any advice on whether it's actually worth it; is there much to be gained from trying to compress what are basically serialized Java objects, or do they not really reduce in size much?

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend `SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor` and override the I/O methods with GZIPInput/Output-Stream  [example](http://www.xpj.cz/expee/2009/06/spring-remoting-with-gzip-compression/)

Comment: looks promising will give it a crack!  I like the fact that's app-server independent too.

Comment: Works nicely - brings our 525,000 byte request down to just over 12,000.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put Apache in front of Tomcat then you'd do it using Apache web server

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Regardless, Tomcat itself just already supports GZIP out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the comment BalusC. Sure Apache is just one way of doing it. I like to put Apache in front of servlet container for numerous reasons among which GZipping responses. On apache it's configuration and no coding. I find it easier to maintain. But that's just me :)

Comment: I don't think Apache config alone would work with Spring HttpInvoker request/responses